# What does 'lazy' mean in the sentence 'They bought the mansion for a lazy $10 million.'?

Tags: meaning

It seems to me that 'lazy' in this context suggests a humorous, off-hand attitude to a sum most would consider serious money. Is it a jocular minimisation of the amount, almost the opposite of the maximisation implied in 'a cool $10 million'?

Comment: Yes, it's either that, or implying they simply paid the asking price and put no effort into negotiating. We won't be able to tell you for sue unless you provide more context for your quote.

Comment: I think they refer to money that were not properly invested, as if they had been left idle.  *Don't turn your liquid assets into lazy money. Reach out a few years on the yield curve.* https://books.google.it/books?id=gBm8AAAAIAAJ&q=%22lazy+money%22&dq=%22lazy+money%22&hl=it&sa=X&ei=IpRlVZfqBobLyAP1h4BQ&ved=0CF4Q6AEwCA

Comment: Are you sure it wasn't _lousy $10 million_?

Comment: @jimmy If you provide more context or the source of the sentence , you might get a better answer.

Comment: @Barmar 
whether it was a lazy or a lousy, seems like a use of sarcasm. Or opposite of "hyperbole" - meiosis, understatement

Comment: In the same vein as Josh61's comment, I suspect that _lazy [money]_ here might mean something like "[money] just sitting around doing nothing."

Comment: Jimmy, do you have a link to the original source text for this? Or are you repeating this from something you heard?

Comment: @Mitch and P. Obertelli above: there is no original source text. This is a construction I've come across in the past. I made up the sentence after spending some time trying to find an actual example on the web. 

The trouble is that 'lazy' used in this sense is quite rare, so you have to wade through a lot or irrelevant Google responses before you find a case in point. I'm hoping some of you commenters have also come across it, so that you know it's not a figment of my imagination.

Comment: Oh, then you were able to find _something_ online through Google. Since you've already done that it'll be much easier for you to find it again  than it will be for us who believe it doesn't exist or is an error for 'a lousy. $10mil'. We expect that people mean what we heard them say, but there's lots of room for mistakes starting from their brain all the way to ours.

Answer (score 1):

It's not impossible to construct a sentence that, in context, uses "a lazy $10 million" in a meaningful way, but the phrase seems not to be an established English idiom. Google Books searches for the phrases "a lazy sum" and "a lazy amount," for example, turn up no matches in the Google Books database.

Here's a scenario where "a lazy $10 million" might work:

> In going over their portfolio, Don and his then-wife realized that they had tens of millions of dollars sitting around doing nothing—neither accumulating interest nor appreciating in value. So they began looking at investment properties and found a large house that appeared to be worth more than the asking price. After some pro forma dickering, **they bought the mansion for a lazy $10 million**.

In this situation, you could characterize the $10 million as lazy because it wasn't increasing in value until converted into a deed to the mansion. But as I said, this is a one-off invention; as far as I know, the phrase "a lazy $XXX" is not an English idiom.

Answer (score 0):

Etymologically "LAZY" means averse to work or effortless-- lack of desire to expend effort.
In the present context 'lazy $ 10 million' suggests that the sum was paid effortlessly; it didn't matter much to them and they arranged the amount easily, perhaps the amount was damn cheap and very much within their reach.

A precise step by step calculation is involved to arrive at bargain price or contractual price. Here we may shift to another meaning of "LAZY".

•(comptheory) Employing lazy evaluation. Not calculating results until they are immediately require. A lazy algorithm.

So the Price was paid just casually without going into detailed niceties of the trouble of price calculation as the sum was within their means.
It may mean either way:-the price induced a kind of laziness or they're men of very great means.

On the whole as we pass a lazy afternoon lazily, similarly they paid the lazy sum without much of an effort.

Answer (score -1):

It means it was easy for them - well within their financial means.

Comment: While I agree with you, you should link to some definition that proves what you're saying. Otherwise, for all we know you could be making the whole thing up.

Comment: Hello DrSpleen, and welcome to English Language & Usage. Interpreting "lazy" as meaning "not a stretch financially" is appealing, but it's not the only possible interpretation—see the comments beneath the poster's question for others. To strengthen your answer, please consider supplementing it with a citation to a reference work that interprets _lazy_ in the same way that you do. Thanks!